# Regular local rings are normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $(A, \mathfrak{m}, k)$ be a local ring, and let $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(A)$ be its associated graded ring. On page 123 of Atiyah-MacDonald, the following is stated without proof, and not given as an exercise:

> It can also be shown that if $A$ is a local ring and $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(A)$ is an integrally closed integral domain, then $A$ is integrally closed.

Restricting to the case of regular local rings, i.e. $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(A) \cong k[T_1, T_2, \ldots, T_d]$, this clearly follows from the theorem of Auslander and Buchsbaum that $A$ is a unique factorization domain. Is this true for reasons independent their result (or the global dimension argument by Serre)?

Comment: I don't know how you used the theorem of Auslander and Buchsbaum to show that $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(A) \simeq k[T_1, \ldots, T_d]$, but this follows from the fact that $\mathfrak m$ is generated by a system of parametres which in this case is a regular sequence.

Comment: I haven't. That characterization of regular local rings via their associated graded ring is proved in Theorem 11.22 of Atiyah-MacDonald. The theorem of Auslander and Buchsbaum is a statement about $A$, rather than about $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(A)$. It uses extensive arguments from homological algebra that I don't really understand, so my real question is, "How can we find information about $A$ from $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(A)$ without using global dimension?"

Comment: I found a proof under the additional assumption that $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(A)$ is noetherian, which I can post later today. Do you know if Bruns and Herzog make this assumption?